# How do I checkout an older version in Intellij idea using git?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I want to modify an older version of a program which is available on GitHub.

So in idea I did:

VCS -> checkout from version control -> GitHub

entered the url and this way I received the current version of the program.
Now, what do I have to do?

I tried:

VCS -> show changes view -> right-click on the version I want to edit -> checkout revision

but now there are just some .iml and .xml files left in the project window.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: do you see the 'HEAD' mark next to the desired revision at the changes view? If so - you have successfully checked out the old version you wanted. Switch to the 'local' tab to check that there are no garbage leftover.

Comment: okay, i see the mark so the problem must be somewhere else. thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

i did it in the right way (see my question), the problem lies somewhere else.
 but i dropped the project anyway.

Answer (score 0):

press `Alt+9`.
Then right-click on the commit that you want to check out. then select `reset current branch to here`.
more detail on JetBrain's official website. [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/use-tags-to-mark-specific-commits.html#tag_commit)